# design question for java SWING app

Tags: java, oop, swing

Note: This is for a SWING course I am taking.

I have an assignment to make a simple graphics package (draw circles, squares, etc).

I was thinking of having multiple dialog boxes for entering the shape parameters, i.e:

Point has x,y
Circle has x,y,radius
Rectangle has x,y,width,height
etc.

I was thinking of creating a super dialog class with X,Y and extending it to allow for Width,Height or Radius etc.

For example, the rectangleDialog would invoke the super constructor with the additional parameters required:

```
public abstract class XYDialog extends JFrame {
   public XYDialog(PARAMETERS ... params) {
       // build the dialog by iterating through PARAMETERS
   }
}


public class RectangleDialog extends XYDialog {
  public RectangleDialog() {
    super(PARAMETERS.WIDTH, PARAMETERS.HEIGHT);
  }
}
```

then the super class is responsible for building the GUI

Does this seem like a reasonable approach?  Does this make sense?

Thanks

Comment: There is a completely different Dialog Swing class http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html for textual messages so you shouldn't use those names. Make it clear whether you actually want a Swing Dialog or you want to draw in it

Comment: As a bonus advice, I'd use `super(PARAMETERS.WIDTH | PARAMETERS.HEIGHT)` instead of a variable number of parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think it's a good solution. But, as stated before, reconsider the naming of your classes. If you extend a JFrame, call it SomethingFrame. If PARAMETERS is a normal class, it should not be in capitals.

I would also suggest extending JPanel instead of JFrame, and let the one instatiating these classes determine if to put them in a JFrame or a JDialog. A JFrame creates a whole new window, and you normally only have one main window for your application, whereas dialogs and panels are created on the fly.

Comment: "I would also suggest extending JPanel instead of JFrame, and let the one instatiating these classes determine if to put them in a JFrame or a JDialog. " ..or a JOptionPane, or a JToolBar, or a WEST constraint in a BorderLayout ..